# Reading mails using Spring email abstraction layer

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

Spring provides abstraction over JavaMail Api.

There are lot of examples to describe how to send mail using spring email abstraction layer.

but how can i read  emails using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because Spring does not have a built-in support for receiving e-mails?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html:

> ### 24. Email
>
> #### 24.1 Introduction
>
> The Spring Framework provides a helpful utility library for **sending email** that shields the user from the specifics of the underlying mailing system and is responsible for low level resource handling on behalf of the client.

If you want to receive e-mails you must use some external libraries, including Spring Integration with [POP3 support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#mail-inbound).

Comment: Can you suggest any external library for the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Spring to poll for emails from a POP or IMAP server

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html

Or access directly.

```
MailReceiver receiver = new Pop3MailReceiver("pop3://usr:pwd@localhost/INBOX");
```

Comment: I try to use MailReceiver class (Spring intergration dependency added) but my IDEA cannot find it :(