# Calling my endpoint when receiving a new email

Tags: java, email, mail-server

I'm looking for a reliable service that will manage an Email box & servers for me.
I want it to call my endpoint (with the message inside) on each email it receiving.

Any existing solutions for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[spring-integration](/questions/tagged/spring-integration) can do it easily, see [Reading mails using Spring email abstraction layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792458). Basically every [esb](/questions/tagged/esb) system can read e-mails and forward them to any other endpoint, like WS, file, IM account.